# Unable to splice array of objects

Tags: javascript

I was able to shuffle through my deck of cards (array of objects), but now I'm trying to pull out/remove the first 25 cards(objects) and place them into their own stored array. However, my code is returning undefined when I try to reference the new deck cards  var player1Deck = shuffledCards.splice(25); is returning as not a function. Is there anyway to remove the first 25 cards/object from this new shuffled array that I created?

```js
    //Deck with ranks
   var starterDeck = [
    {"img": '2_of_clubs.png',"rank": 1},{"img": '3_of_clubs.png',"rank": 2},{"img": '4_of_clubs.png',"rank": 3},{"img": '5_of_clubs.png',"rank": 4},{"img": '6_of_clubs.png',"rank": 5},{"img": '7_of_clubs.png',"rank": 6},{"img": '8_of_clubs.png',"rank": 7},{"img": '9_of_clubs.png',"rank": 8},{"img": '10_of_clubs.png',"rank": 9},{"img": 'jack_of_clubs.png',"rank": 10},{"img": 'queen_of_clubs.png',"rank": 11},{"img": 'king_of_clubs.png',"rank": 12},{"img": 'ace_of_clubs.png',"rank": 13},    {"img": '2_of_diamonds.png',"rank": 1},{"img": '3_of_diamonds.png',"rank": 2},{"img": '4_of_diamonds.png',"rank": 3},{"img": '5_of_diamonds.png',"rank": 4},{"img": '6_of_diamonds.png',"rank": 5},{"img": '7_of_diamonds.png',"rank": 6},{"img": '8_of_diamonds.png',"rank": 7},{"img": '9_of_diamonds.png',"rank": 8},{"img": '10_of_diamonds.png',"rank": 9},{"img": 'jack_of_diamonds.png',"rank": 10},{"img": 'queen_of_diamonds.png',"rank": 11},{"img": 'king_of_diamonds.png',"rank": 12},{"img": 'ace_of_diamonds.png',"rank": 13},    {"img": '2_of_hearts.png',"rank": 1},{"img": '3_of_hearts.png',"rank": 2},{"img": '4_of_hearts.png',"rank": 3},{"img": '5_of_hearts.png',"rank": 4},{"img": '6_of_hearts.png',"rank": 5},{"img": '7_of_hearts.png',"rank": 6},{"img": '8_of_hearts.png',"rank": 7},{"img": '9_of_hearts.png',"rank": 8},{"img": '10_of_hearts.png',"rank": 9},{"img": 'jack_of_hearts.png',"rank": 10},{"img": 'queen_of_hearts.png',"rank": 11},{"img": 'king_of_hearts.png',"rank": 12},{"img": 'ace_of_hearts.png',"rank": 13},    {"img": '2_of_spades.png',"rank": 1},{"img": '3_of_spades.png',"rank": 2},{"img": '4_of_spades.png',"rank": 3},{"img": '5_of_spades.png',"rank": 4},{"img": '6_of_spades.png',"rank": 5},{"img": '7_of_spades.png',"rank": 6},{"img": '8_of_spades.png',"rank": 7},{"img": '9_of_spades.png',"rank": 8},{"img": '10_of_spades.png',"rank": 9},{"img": 'jack_of_spades.png',"rank": 10},{"img": 'queen_of_spades.png',"rank": 11},{"img": 'king_of_spades.png',"rank": 12},{"img": 'ace_of_spades.png',"rank": 13},
   ]

        for(var i=0;i<52; i++) {
            // We are taking our tempCard and placing it in the random position (randomIndex)
            var shuffledCards = starterDeck[i];
            var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
            starterDeck[i] = starterDeck[randomIndex]
            starterDeck[randomIndex] = shuffledCards;
           // let newDeck = [shuffledCards]
            console.log(shuffledCards)

            var player1Deck = shuffledCards.splice(25);
            console.log(player1Deck)
        }
```

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(shuffledCards)`? It looks like you're setting shuffledCards to a single card in the for loop, so it wouldn't be an array, therefore you wouldn't be able to splice. You'll probably want to move any logic that deals with the whole deck to after the for loop.

Comment: `shuffledCards = starterDeck[i]` - `shuffledCards` is not an array

Comment: What are you hoping `shuffledCards.splice(25)` will do?

Answer (score 0):

Splice works like that: splice(objectIndex, steps). For example in an array of [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] if I do arr.splice(2,2) it will remove 5 and 6. Splice does not return anything as it removes items from array on the place (like forEach function compared to .map which returns new array). If you want to split the decks (first 26 items), use .slice instead => slice(0, 26) or better slice(0, arr.length / 2)
I see your a newbie, so please, dont use vars, let & const are new methods to proclaim variables. Perhaps your tutorial is outdated

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```js
const starterDeck = [{
    "img": '2_of_clubs.png',
    "rank": 1
}, {
    "img": '3_of_clubs.png',
    "rank": 2
}, {
    "img": '4_of_clubs.png',
    "rank": 3
}, {
    "img": '5_of_clubs.png',
    "rank": 4
}, {
    "img": '6_of_clubs.png',
    "rank": 5
}, {
    "img": '7_of_clubs.png',
    "rank": 6
}, {
    "img": '8_of_clubs.png',
    "rank": 7
}, {
    "img": '9_of_clubs.png',
    "rank": 8
}, {
    "img": '10_of_clubs.png',
    "rank": 9
}, {
    "img": 'jack_of_clubs.png',
    "rank": 10
}, {
    "img": 'queen_of_clubs.png',
    "rank": 11
}, {
    "img": 'king_of_clubs.png',
    "rank": 12
}, {
    "img": 'ace_of_clubs.png',
    "rank": 13
}, {
    "img": '2_of_diamonds.png',
    "rank": 1
}, {
    "img": '3_of_diamonds.png',
    "rank": 2
}, {
    "img": '4_of_diamonds.png',
    "rank": 3
}, {
    "img": '5_of_diamonds.png',
    "rank": 4
}, {
    "img": '6_of_diamonds.png',
    "rank": 5
}, {
    "img": '7_of_diamonds.png',
    "rank": 6
}, {
    "img": '8_of_diamonds.png',
    "rank": 7
}, {
    "img": '9_of_diamonds.png',
    "rank": 8
}, {
    "img": '10_of_diamonds.png',
    "rank": 9
}, {
    "img": 'jack_of_diamonds.png',
    "rank": 10
}, {
    "img": 'queen_of_diamonds.png',
    "rank": 11
}, {
    "img": 'king_of_diamonds.png',
    "rank": 12
}, {
    "img": 'ace_of_diamonds.png',
    "rank": 13
}, {
    "img": '2_of_hearts.png',
    "rank": 1
}, {
    "img": '3_of_hearts.png',
    "rank": 2
}, {
    "img": '4_of_hearts.png',
    "rank": 3
}, {
    "img": '5_of_hearts.png',
    "rank": 4
}, {
    "img": '6_of_hearts.png',
    "rank": 5
}, {
    "img": '7_of_hearts.png',
    "rank": 6
}, {
    "img": '8_of_hearts.png',
    "rank": 7
}, {
    "img": '9_of_hearts.png',
    "rank": 8
}, {
    "img": '10_of_hearts.png',
    "rank": 9
}, {
    "img": 'jack_of_hearts.png',
    "rank": 10
}, {
    "img": 'queen_of_hearts.png',
    "rank": 11
}, {
    "img": 'king_of_hearts.png',
    "rank": 12
}, {
    "img": 'ace_of_hearts.png',
    "rank": 13
}, {
    "img": '2_of_spades.png',
    "rank": 1
}, {
    "img": '3_of_spades.png',
    "rank": 2
}, {
    "img": '4_of_spades.png',
    "rank": 3
}, {
    "img": '5_of_spades.png',
    "rank": 4
}, {
    "img": '6_of_spades.png',
    "rank": 5
}, {
    "img": '7_of_spades.png',
    "rank": 6
}, {
    "img": '8_of_spades.png',
    "rank": 7
}, {
    "img": '9_of_spades.png',
    "rank": 8
}, {
    "img": '10_of_spades.png',
    "rank": 9
}, {
    "img": 'jack_of_spades.png',
    "rank": 10
}, {
    "img": 'queen_of_spades.png',
    "rank": 11
}, {
    "img": 'king_of_spades.png',
    "rank": 12
}, {
    "img": 'ace_of_spades.png',
    "rank": 13
}, ];

let player1Deck = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
    const shuffledCards = starterDeck[i];
    starterDeck[i] = starterDeck[randomIndex];
    starterDeck[randomIndex] = shuffledCards;
    player1Deck = starterDeck.slice(25);
}

console.log(player1Deck)
```

**Analysis**

You were trying to slice from `shuffledCards` but this is an object for your swapping logic. Instead you should get cards from `starterDeck`.

```
 player1Deck = starterDeck.slice(25); // Slice doesn't manipulate new array
```

Also updated the code with new ES6+ features.

Answer (score 0):

You try to use an Array method over *shuffledCards* but in the code every time the loop run you define *shuffledCards* again and you assign it an object as value

```
var shuffledCards = starterDeck[i];
```

*starterDeck* is an Array so if you do *starterDeck[i]* you get the value of that position (an Object)

Try to define *starterDeck* out of the loop and inside the loop you going to push the values then outside the loop you use *splice(0, 25)*

This way you delete from 0 position up to 25 position of Array.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you are using the splice method on an object, that's why you're getting the error.
Since splice is a method used on arrays, you can fix the problem by adding all the shuffle cards to an array first before applying splice.

Something like the code below should work.

```
    const allShuffledCards = []
    for(var i=0;i<52; i++) {
                // We are taking our tempCard and placing it in the random position (randomIndex)
                var shuffledCards = starterDeck[i];
                var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * 52);
                starterDeck[i] = starterDeck[randomIndex]
                starterDeck[randomIndex] = shuffledCards;
               // let newDeck = [shuffledCards]
                console.log(shuffledCards)
    
                allShuffledCards.push(shuffledCards);
                console.log(player1Deck)
            }
   allShuffledCards.splice(0, 25)
   console.log(allShuffledCards)
```